# Catch all exceptions

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions

Is it possible to catch all Azure Function exceptions in one place, just like `IExceptionFilter` or `Application_Error` in global.asax for ASP.NET?

Also, is it possible to grab the current HttpRequestMessage to get the context of the exception?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Function Filters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Function-Filters) for that; however, they only work with precompiled functions using the attribute model see [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/) for more info